# Next auth middleware { default } is not working

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

middleware.ts

```js
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';
export const config = { matcher: ['/my/:path*'] };
```

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware

now im using like this, but code is not working

I hope middleware works when accessing pages related to 'my'.
how can i fix it?

```
"next": "^12.0.8",
"next-auth": "^4.10.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

this is my packages version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the issue might be the way in which you are creating the `middleware` file, since everything else looks good to me.

Since Next.js 12.2, now you have to create a single `middleware.ts` file in your root directory (same level as `pages` folder). But on earlier versions like the one you are using, you need to create a `_middleware.ts` (notice the underscore) file **inside** your `pages` folder.

**Reference:** https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide#breaking-changes

Comment: thank you! that was my next js version problem.

Comment: ahh, the same level as pages, that means it is in the "src" folder. the documentation is somehow vague about this ...

Answer (score 7):

In nextjs version "13.0.7" you have to put middleware.ts in the same level with the pages folder. If the pages folder is in root add it in root level. If the pages folder is inside src you have to add it inside src folder. Worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 6):

This code below worked for me. Using Next 13.3.0 and next-auth 4.21.1.

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import { prisma } from '@/lib/prismadb';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
    }),
  ],
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
};

export default NextAuth({
  ...authOptions,
});
```

middleware.ts

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // Get the pathname of the request (e.g. /, /protected)
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  // If it's the root path, just render it
  if (path === '/') {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const session = await getToken({
    req,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  const isProtected = path.includes('/dashboard');

  if (!session && isProtected) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/restore', req.url));
  } else if (session && (path === '/restore' || path === '/register')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked better for me in next: 13.4.8 pages directory with next-auth: 4.15.0.

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const session = !!req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")

  if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=${path}`, req.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)','/boards', '/workspace/:path*']
}
```

Comment: this is the correct method to protect pages with middleware, why this is not in the docs?

next-auth docs are very poor specially for "app" directory users, and Nextjs need to either clarify these stuff for users or adapt another main library for auth

Answer (score 3):

I got same problem with next-auth^4.22.1 + next^13.4.5, but solution ease: if you use folder *src*, *middleware.ts* (js) need put inside folder, this will work.
**Lahiru Lanka Rathnayaka** thx for answer)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I created the middleware but somehow on the page it can detect if it is signed in but after redirecting to the page middleware thought I didn't signin which is bizarre, looks like server side middleware uses different session than frontend stuff

Comment: same behaviour for me

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but I had a similar issue using the middleware to redirect unauthorized users to the login page while working with nextjs 13.4.4 and next-auth 4.22.1.

Fixed it by upgrading to a canary version of next (13.4.5-canary.0) though you can wait till the release of nextjs 13.4.5 stable version then upgrade.

to upgrade to latest canary version of nextjs

```
install --save next@canary
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add middleware.ts to the tsconfig.json in order for it to be included:

```
…

  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "middleware.ts"
  ],
…
```